# How to connect the ground wires that are bunched together in my receptacle

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I'm updating my light switches in the garage to use an occupancy light, which requires a ground to function. Inside the receptacle I can see that the two previous switches were not grounded, and I see a bundle of 5 copper cables crimped together.

[image]

What's the best way to connect a ground wire to my new occupancy switch? I was attempting to cut off the crimp, but read online that all ground wires should be crimped/grouped together.

Comment: That box is too deep into the wall.  You will need a box extension sleeve to correct it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a crimp, use a **wire nut**. There are different sizes available, depending on the number and size of the wires included. You add one more bare or green wire to the existing bundle, and connect that to your new switch.